# How can I validate a string to only allow string or string with numbers but not numbers only?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have textbox i want to give it expression for allowing string only or string with numbers but not to allow numbers only .. is this possible or not?

thanks guys your answers are really helpful but theres another issue tho
can i prevent user also from writing these symbols : or ` or " or ) or [ or { or ~ or . or / etc.. i mean any symbols like those ones!

After @rinukkusu helped me with regex theres still one last thing though I dont want to allow the user to start the string with number and not in between also.. i want any number to be in the end of the string. I really appreciate your effort. Thanks!

heres the regex i used

```
(?!^\d+$)^[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

Comment: [Use regular expression validator...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, just *ask* for any sequence of numbers or digit but require that at least one letter is there:

```
/^(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

It means: first group is any number of digits (considering whole string because it's tied to both begin and end), it's not allowed. Second group is any alpanumeric sequence long at least one character. Because first match will exclude numbers only then if this one is matche your text contains at least one character.

Comment: thanks, but can i prevent user also from writing the letter ` or "" or ) or [ or { or ~ or . or / etc.. i mean any symbols like those ones

Comment: @user3177576 Yes, only letters and digits. I'm not such good with regex (always keep my static class for all-topics regex untouched as much as possible) so I suppose you can simplify this somehow (_d_ for digits, for example).

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem.
**Update**: and only matches letters, underscores and of course numbers but not only numbers

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator
    ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
    runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="Your error message"
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
    ValidationExpression="(?!^\d+$)^\w+$" >
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

If you want to specify which characters should be matched only, try this expression:

```
(?!^\d+$)^[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

Comment: hey bud, I dont know if you're still there but you were very helpful but now i need the expression to not start with number and no numbers also between strings just in the end of the string and no underscores either.. if you could help me with that I'd appreciate your effort. Thanks!

Comment: @user3177576 you should **post a new question** if your requirements change, to keep asking changing topic and request isn't good for SO. That said **try by yourself first**, now you know "[a-zA-Z0-9]+" will match any alphanumeric sequence of at least one character. "[a-zA-Z]" will match any sequence of letters and "[0-9]" a sequence of digits...put them together: at least one letter and optionally one or more digits. It's even simpler than the other regex.

Comment: I already post a new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158912/regex-i-need-to-put-numbers-in-the-end-of-the-string
and I really tried by myself and try searching for it too but I really not that good with Regex :(

Comment: btw this that what i got so far
(?!^\d+$)^[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+$
it has one problem though it doesnt allow strings only?

Comment: @user3177576 `+` means _one or more characters_ then you're asking for _at least one digit_ at the end of your string. Replace `[0-9]+$` with `[0-9]*$`. Moreover IMO `\d+$` should be `\d*$`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression. If the string is matched as a number, the input is invalid. Example:

```
string input = "2cc3d"; //valid

if(Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\d+$"))
    Console.WriteLine("NOT VALID");
else
    Console.WriteLine("VALID");
```

If you don't want to do this in code, you should use the solution provided by "rinukkusu".