# RegEx I need to put numbers in the end of the string?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I asked this question yesterday and people on stackoverflow were really helpful, so anyway this the regex that i got so far:

[How can I validate a string to only allow string or string with numbers but not numbers only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142208/how-can-i-validate-a-string-to-only-allow-string-or-string-with-numbers-but-not)

(?!^\d+$)^[A-Za-z0-9]+$

it doesn't allow numbers only or symbols or spaces or underscores what i need next i want it to not start with numbers and no numbers in between also but allow to end with any number so please help?

Comment: Please, give some strings that must match and some that mustn't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one **(?!\d).*[?\d{1}]**

Is this what your requirement is?

EDIT: Please check the comments below, the user got the answer that was needed

Comment: but this Regex allow underscores and doesnt allow strings without numbers. what I want is to make my textbox allow string only or string with numbers but numbers in the end of the string and no spaces, symbols, underscores and no numbers only. is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is definately possible.. why dont you try youself online?? Check out this link http://regexpal.com/

Comment: this what i got so far (?!^\d+$)^[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+$
but it doesnt allow strings only?

Comment: I dont know if this will help you.. try this.. (?!^\d+$)^[A-Za-z]+([0-9]+)?$

Comment: thanks alot Harish this exactly what i need :)
excuse me cuz Im all new to the programming world so I really try my best :) so if you dont mind can you try to explain to me this Regex code we got like what is )? for, cuz Im not that good for understanding the Regex sequence?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: **upvote** posts or comments which **helped or solved** your problem.

What you asked for in the comments: [Explaining the regular expression provided by Harish](http://www.regexper.com/#%28%3F!%5E%5Cd%2B%24%29%28%5E%5BA-Za-z%5D%2B%28%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%3F%24%29)

- The negative lookahead checks, if the string not only matches digits.
- Group #1:

  - check for characters matching A-Z and a-z
  - check for appearance of digits at the end but only the end of the string